# AppleScript: Finder Sorting

Tags: sorting, applescript

So I'm pretty new at AppleScript, but I'm trying to make a script to sort my video files.

I can't really seem to work out the fault in this one. Nothing happens. Anyone got a clue?

a possible explanation may be that the folders are om my home server and not on the hard drive?

```applescript
property nameList : {"Arrow"} -- the start of the fileName to check
property destFoldersPath : {"/Volumes/media/Videos/Serier/Arrow"} -- drag/drop the dest folder in each item of this list

on adding folder items to masterFolder after receiving these_items
    repeat with tFile in these_items
        set destFolder to my check_start_of_Name(tFile as string)
        if destFolder is not "" then -- this file name is in the first list
            tell application "Finder" to move tFile to destFolder with replacing --move this file
        end if
    end repeat
end adding folder items to

on check_start_of_Name(t)
    set tc to count nameList
    repeat with i from 1 to tc
        if t starts with (item i of nameList) then
            set seasonPath to my check_season_of_Name(t)
            set outputPath to (POSIX file (item i of destFoldersPath))
            set completePath to outputPath & seasonPath as alias
            if FinderItemNotExists(completePath) then
                tell application "Finder"
                    make new folder at outputPath with properties {name:seasonPath}
                end tell
            end if
            log outputPath
            return outputPath as alias -- return the dest folder
        end if
    end repeat
    return "" -- this name is not in the list
end check_start_of_Name

on check_season_of_Name(t)
    repeat with s from 1 to 30
        set SW to s
        if s is less than 10 then set SW to "0" & s
        set seasonName to "Season " & SW
        log seasonName
        if seasonName is in t then
            return seasonName
        end if
    end repeat
end check_season_of_Name

on FinderItemNotExists(thePath)
    try
        set thePath to thePath as alias
    on error
        return true
    end try
    return false
end FinderItemNotExists
```

Comment: There's too much "noise", which makes it hard to understand the problem; try to narrow the issue down and describe specific symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your script. I was unfamiliar with Folder Action scripts so this was educational. Here is what I understood you are trying to achieve from your code - please correct me if I am wrong:

1. Your files are named like this: "{Show name} {Season XX} etc"
2. Processes files whose name begins with the names a list, ignores the rest.
3. Determines the season from the file names and creates folders named 'Season XX'.
4. Finally it moves the files to these folders.

So I started from the beginning and line by line fixed, as best I know, what was was not working. As you can see below, I've left all the debugging statements. You can watch them by running the following command,

```
$ tail -f /var/log/system.log | grep 'Debug:'
```

I tested it by creating a dummy file, based on the convention you seem to use, and simply copy/pasted while I was keeping an eye on the log for the debug statements.

PS: If you remove the `on adding folder items` lines and insert the following at the top

```
set these_items to (choose file) as list
```

you can run and debug your code inside the Applescript Editor. Using `log` to debug it was very tedious...

So here is the code:

```
property nameList : {"Arrow"} -- the start of the fileName to check
property destFoldersPath : {"/Volumes/media/Videos/Serier/Arrow"} -- drag/drop the dest folder in each item of this list

on adding folder items to masterFolder after receiving these_items

    log "Debug: New file detected!"

    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        repeat with tFile in these_items
            set fName to (get name of tFile)
            #log "Debug: Item name: " & fName

            set destFolder to my check_start_of_Name(fName)
            log "Debug: Destiantion Folder: " & destFolder

            if destFolder is not "" then -- this file name is in the first list
                 move tFile to destFolder with replacing --move this file
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end adding folder items to

on check_start_of_Name(t)
    set tc to count nameList
    #log "Debug: List count is: " & tc
    log "Debug: Item name: " & t

    repeat with i from 1 to tc
        if t starts with (item i of nameList) then
            log "Debug: Checking for TV Series: " & item i of nameList

            set seasonPath to my check_season_of_Name(t)
            #log "Debug: Season Path: " & seasonPath

            set outputPath to (POSIX file (item i of destFoldersPath))
            log "Debug: Output path is: " & outputPath

            #set completePath to outputPath & seasonPath as alias
            # Can't create alias, a dymanic object, of something that may not exist... so...

            set completePath to (outputPath as text) & ":" & seasonPath & ":"
            log "Debug: Complete path is: " & completePath

            # Lets use the POSIX path to test for the existance of the folder...
            set posixPath to (POSIX path of (completePath as text))
            log "Debug: Posix path is: " & posixPath

            if FinderItemNotExists(posixPath) then
                log "Debug: Seacon folder not found, creating..."
                tell application "Finder"
                    make new folder at outputPath with properties {name:seasonPath}
                end tell
            else
                log "Debug: Folder exists."
            end if

            # Shouldn't we return the new folder we just created or deduced?
            #return outputPath as alias -- return the dest folder

            # So I think you mean...
            return completePath as alias
        end if
    end repeat
    log "Debug: Name not found in list!"
    return "" -- this name is not in the list
end check_start_of_Name

on check_season_of_Name(t)
    log "Debug: Checking season in filename: " & t
    repeat with s from 1 to 30
        set SW to s
        if s is less than 10 then set SW to "0" & s
        set seasonName to "Season " & SW
        #log seasonName
        if seasonName is in t then
            log "Debug: Found season: " & seasonName
            return seasonName
        end if
    end repeat
    log "Debug: Season name not found!"
end check_season_of_Name

on FinderItemNotExists(thePath)
    try
        do shell script "test -d '" & thePath & "'"
        return false
    on error
        return true
    end try
end FinderItemNotExists
```